# Does Sharepoint use the wWWHomePage attribute in AD?

Tags: active-directory, profile-sync

I have been working with synchronizing users into Active Directory, from an external data source, and one of the attributes of interest is wWWHomePage, and the AD folk have noticed that many users have this set to their SharePoint home page.

There is a belief but they cannot prove (nor find) why this is getting set.  They believe that they may have SharePoint set up (another group manages SharePoint) to set this.

Is this normal SharePoint behavior, and is there any downside to changing this for users?

Comment: Is it being populated with their MySites URL? Could be a userprofile sync thing...

Answer (score 2):

When the user first provisions or accesses their MySite they are prompted if the want Microsoft Office to remember the location of their MySite. I believe if the user selects "Yes" it writes the value to AD, but I have never reverse engineered this to see how it actually works. I believe the value is being updated directly into AD and is not using User Profile Sync to write it. This behavior has been in SharePoint since 2003.

Comment: So how bad is it, if you overwrite that attribute value?

Comment: It won't break SharePoint, but it may impact Office integration like Quick Links, etc. I don't know exactly which features in Office depend on it.